# List of tuples to nested dictionary without overriding

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to convert the above list of tuples to nested dictionary without overwriting the value as below in python

```
[('a', '1'),
  ('b', 'true'),
  ('b', 'none'),
  ('a', '2'),
  ('b', 'true'),
  ('a', '3'),
  ('b', 'false')]


{'a': {'1' : { 'b' : ('true','none')},
       '2' : { 'b' : ('true')},
       '3' : { 'b' : ('false')}}}
```

Converting each tuple into dictionary using

```
dict()
```

and merging the dictionary doesn't work. Is there any pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear. Are you sure that each tuple will be `'a'` or `'b'` followed by an integer in string form or a data item to place in a tuple? Are the integers (in string format) guaranteed to be consecutive? [I must say, I do not see the point to such a dictionary structure, with only one `'a'` and those repetitive `'b'`'s--none of which are adding any information.]

Comment: I will suggest you iterating over your list and decomposing it to `key` and `value` from its tuple, then check if the `key` already exists in your `dictionary` getting its previous `tuple` value, convert it to `list` appending the new `value` to it and then again make it a `tuple` and set it as the new dictionary `key`. If it's not clear let me know and I will give the **actual python code** *ASAP* `:)`

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, each tuple will be 'a' or 'b' followed by some data which will be a string. Integers shown here is for example. It need not to be a consecutive.

Comment: @Alex , may I ask, what are you trying to achieve ? what problem are you solving ?

Comment: @MaskedMan It would be helpful if you could you share me the code with the result as I am still confused.

Comment: @Alex, I'll be home in a couple of hours and will give you the code `:)`

Comment: @UriGoren If you see that list of tuples it has three identical blocks like

Comment: The list looks the result from lexing (tokenizing) some homebrewn data format. Whether it is or not, you might want to use a parser to interpret it.

Comment: Also, please state the general rule for going one nesting level deeper or one up. You might think they are evident from the example, but there are actually several rules possible that fulfill the example but would give different results on other examples.

Comment: @das-g If you see the list of tuples it has three identical blocks like ('a', '1'), ('b', 'true'), ('b', 'none') and ('a', '2'), ('b', 'true') and ('a', '3'), ('b', 'false'). Each block has  'a' as a common value. I need to form a nested dictionary making it as parent key and values associated with each block as its values

Comment: Can you please edit that information into the question itself? Also, is each 'a'-block guaranteed to have a nonzero number of 'b' entries?

Comment: @das-g Yes.' a' is guaranteed to have a non zero number of b entries

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint

data = [('a', '1'), ('b', 'true'), ('b', 'none'), ('a', '2'), ('b', 'true'), ('a', '3'), ('b', 'false')]

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(tuple)))    
for i, j in data:
    if i == 'a':
        p = d[i][j]
    else:
        p[i] += j,

pprint.pprint(d)
# {'a': {'1': defaultdict(<class 'tuple'>, {'b': ('true', 'none')}),
#        '2': defaultdict(<class 'tuple'>, {'b': ('true',)}),
#        '3': defaultdict(<class 'tuple'>, {'b': ('false',)})}}
```

You could also use the dictionary's `setdefault` method to return default values for new keys, although the `defaultdict` approach is much cleaner and faster:

```
c = {}
for i, j in data:
    if i == 'a':
        q = c.setdefault(i, {}).setdefault(j, {})
    else:
        q[i] = q.setdefault(i, ()) + (j,)

pprint.pprint(c)
# {'a': {'1': {'b': ('true', 'none')},
#        '2': {'b': ('true',)},
#        '3': {'b': ('false',)}}}
```

Comment: Could use `for i, j in data` instead of `for i in data` to make it look a little neater :)

Comment: @Farhan.K Yes, did that. Looks neater :)

Comment: If there is only `a` in the outer dict, you could actually only generate the inner dict first, and then wrap that in a dict with a key `a`.

Comment: In fact the `b` dict itself is also not necessary if it is only `a` and `b`. So `{'1': ('true', 'none')…` contains the same information.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding [@MosesKoledoye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40340407/473890) answer, if the first value in the dictionary is only `'a'` and `'b'`, you know that the outer dictionary will always contain at most one element using `'a'` as the key and the inner dictionary will always contain at most one element using `'b'` as the key. So in the end you get the same information if it is `{'1': ('true', 'none')…`. You can convert that to your format simply by wrapping the data in some dictionaries. This means you can do the following

```
output = defaultdict(tuple)
for i, j in data:
    if i == 'a':
        current = j
    else:
        # i == 'b'
        output[current] += (j, )
```

This will result in the following:

```
defaultdict(<type 'tuple'>, {'1': ('true', 'none'), '3': ('false',), '2': ('true',)})
```

Now to get it into a dictionary like yours you can do the following:

```
output = {k: {'b': v} for k, v in output.items()}
if output:
    output = {'a': output}
```

Resulting in the following:

```
{'a': {'1': {'b': ('true', 'none')}, '3': {'b': ('false',)}, '2': {'b': ('true',)}}}
```