# Merge list of tuples to a dictionary

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, tuples

I have following list of tuples

```
[
('A-1', 'B-1', 'C'), 
('A-1', 'B-2', 'D'), 
('A-1', 'B-3', 'E'), 
('A-1', 'B-4', 'F'), 
('A-1', 'B-5', 'G')
]
```

and I want to create following dictionary of dictionaries:

```
{A:{"A-1":{"B":{"B-1":"C","B-2":"D","B-3":"E","B-4":"F","B-5":"G"}}}}
```

What is the best option? I have to extract data from a bbdd and generate a JSON file so this conversion will be done many times and it is needed the most efficient solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of tuples to nested dictionary without overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340133/list-of-tuples-to-nested-dictionary-without-overriding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just hacked a solution for you:

```
def convert_function(input):
    output = {}
    for val in input:
        first_dict = output.get(val[0][0], {})
        second_dict = first_dict.get(val[0], {})
        third_dict = second_dict.get(val[1][0], {})

        third_dict[val[1]] = val[2]
        second_dict[val[1][0]] = third_dict
        first_dict[val[0]] = second_dict
    
        output[val[0][0]] = first_dict
    return output

input = [
    ('A-1', 'B-1', 'C'), 
    ('A-1', 'B-2', 'D'), 
    ('A-1', 'B-3', 'E'), 
    ('A-1', 'B-4', 'F'), 
    ('A-1', 'B-5', 'G')
]

print convert_function(input)
```